# Grow effect grid gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery

I'm interested in knowing if there's any open source JS library out there that mimics the effect you can see in the following grid gallery:

http://www.lucrezialantana.com/artist-books/filorosso/

When a user clicks on a thumbnail, it "grows" to full size, while the rest of images remain unchanged.

I don't know how this effect is called, so I don't know how to search for a lib that mimics it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really don't need lib for this. this is just onclick of image change height and width of that image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohits answer is good, but you dont even need jQuery for this (although it does make it easier)

Here is a pure JavaScript/HTML/CSS example:

```js
//Function to change image size
//We do this by adding or removing the CSS class "small"
function growOnClick(evt) {
  //The click image
  var img = evt.target;
  //If class already contains "small"
  if (img.className.indexOf("small") >= 0) {
    //Remove "small"
    img.className = img.className
      .replace(/small/ig, '')
      .replace(/  /ig, ' ');
  } else {
    //Add small
    img.className += " small";
  }
}
//Select all "img" tags with the "growOnClick" class
document
  .querySelectorAll("img.growOnClick")
  .forEach(function(img) {
    //For each image, bind "onclick" event to our function
    img.onclick = growOnClick;
  });
```

```css
img.growOnClick {
  transition: width 2.5s;
  width: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.growOnClick.small {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.lucrezialantana.com/files/gimgs/26_filorosso1.jpg" class="growOnClick small" />
<img src="http://www.lucrezialantana.com/files/gimgs/26_filorosso1.jpg" class="growOnClick small" />
<img src="http://www.lucrezialantana.com/files/gimgs/26_filorosso1.jpg" class="growOnClick small" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom jquery to do this like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ourImages').click(function(){
  $(this).height('500px').width('500px');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.lucrezialantana.com/files/gimgs/26_filorosso1.jpg" width="200px" class="ourImages" />
<img src="http://www.lucrezialantana.com/files/gimgs/26_filorosso3.jpg" width="200px" class="ourImages" />
```